# Monaco editor - how to open search panel programmatically?

Tags: javascript

When you do cmd+f in the [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/), you get the find/search box appear.

Is there a way to have this open when the editor loads, with pre-populated text?

Comment: Are you just using the editor or are you hosting an instance of the editor in your own applicaton?

Comment: I'm hosting the editor within a React application. I appear to have access to a lot or public methods on the react instance, it's just unclear  whether it's possible or not!

Comment: Anyone got any insight into this please?